# Auth in Flutter using storage and cookie (not using Firebase)?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a login screen for Flutter right now. I have two questions related to how it works in Flutter.

1. I have my backend set with React and use cookies for auth check. Is it possible to store cookies like web in Flutter? I have cookie validation backend that it checks for valid cookies. Wondering if I can still use this in Flutter.
2. If I use a local storage approach, do I have to setup a permission request for that? And, if a user rejects then I can't use it correct? Moreover, does android users have access to this file?

I am not using Firebase, I have my own backend. Is there a best practice for Node <---> Flutter auth? Most questions or doc are related to Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for something like Android AccountManager yet, but there are some plugins that do similar things:

https://pub.dev/packages/accountmanager
https://pub.dev/packages/account_manager_plugin

/EDIT:
There is a CookieStore class if you want to store cookie
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/CookieStore-class.html